# What does the process shown in the deadlock graph represent?

Tags: sql-server, deadlock, sql-server-2019, deadlock-graph

I have a windows application that is used by multiple users, often there are deadlocks in the database related to lock resources.

Looking at the deadlock graph I see 2 processes and 2 resources, arrows representing the own/request, and that 1 process is killed to allow the other process to continue. Seems logical so far.

I am trying to understand what exactly does a process in the deadlock graph represents because the query shown when hover over the Process is not the same as the query that holds the lock on the resource. So assuming there is a long transaction- begin transaction, followed by 100 lines of sql and commit. Now will each sql code run in single process?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to read up on the [SQL Server scheduler](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sql-server-sql-server-scheduler) to get [the exact idea](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/thread-and-task-architecture-guide?view=sql-server-ver15) on how this works.

The simple explanination is that she SQL Server OS (SQLOS) is a non-preemptive scheduler where all queries are queued internally and then the SQLOS will schedule the tasks on it's worker threads, which are reserved when the service starts.

So there is not a one-to-one relationship beween connections and worker threads (processes).

There is plenty of information about how to read deadlock graphs, [I like this series](https://www.sqlshack.com/what-is-a-sql-server-deadlock/).

Comment: Does 1 long transaction run in its entirety inside 1 process?

Answer (score 2):

The process ID in the deadlock graph is an internal ID that represents a particular Unit Of Work. It is not related to the operating system's process IDs. As far as the OS is concerned there is only one process. It is purely internal to SQLOS, the internal scheduler which manages worker threads and UOW.

As far as parallelism is concerned: that is correct, it's unclear what the actual question is. The process is attached to the original query.

Comment: Does 1 process run the entire transaction? And then once its done with this transaction, then the same processes runs a different transaction?

Comment: No, I thought I was clear: a process represents some work to be done, and is queued against a worker thread. The threads are long-lived and execute each process in turn

Comment: So 1 transaction (assuming begin transaction followed by 100 lines of code and commit) can run across multiple processes?

Comment: Only if it goes parallel, otherwise there is only one UOW at a time

Comment: Ok and the sql scheduler will handle the transactions concept? The process will only execute what scheduler assigns to the process?

Comment: No, transactions are handled by the process. The scheduler only schedules the process to be run. The scheduler doesn't assign things to the process, it assigns the process to worker threads.

Comment: So suppose there is 1 sql query I fire in management studio tab, it has begin transaction,100 sql code lines, commit. So if you are saying that the process manages transaction then how can it do so without the entire sql query running in that process?